# Windows won't let me format small partition as FAT32, how can I force it to?

Tags: windows, windows-10, format, fat32

I have a 4 GB partition on my hard disk that I'd like to store some recovery tools on. I want to format it as FAT32, but the *Format* window in *Disk Management* lets me choose only NTFS and ReFS.

**How do I format this partition to FAT32 without using third-party tools?**

I'm using Windows 10 Pro, Version 1703.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain what's wrong with this question and how I can improve it.

Answer (score 1):

**Assign it a drive letter.**

Right-click the partition in *Disk Management*, click *Change Drive Letters and Paths* and assign any drive letter. FAT and FAT32 will become available for formatting.

If you're afraid of mounting the partition (viruses and stuff), format it to NTFS first to sanitize it, then mount and format.

Comment: This didn't work in Windows 10.

Comment: @krm What's the size of your partition?

Comment: The size of my partition is 64 GB.

Comment: @krm Windows has an artificial limitation of 32 GB for FAT32 partition sizes. You can use 3rd party tools instead.